# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'com/mysql/cj/configurations/3-0-Compat.properties'

Tags: java, android, mysql

Can somebody help me with this error:

> More than one file was found with OS independent path
>   'com/mysql/cj/configurations/3-0-Compat.properties'

I get this error in android studio.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify your **specific problem** or **add additional details** to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: reformatted the question

Answer (score 0):

```
packagingOptions {       
        exclude 'com/mysql/cj/configurations/3-0-Compat.properties'
        exclude 'com/mysql/cj/configurations/solarisMaxPerformance.properties'
        exclude 'com/mysql/cj/configurations/clusterBase.properties'
        exclude 'com/mysql/cj/configurations/coldFusion.properties'
        exclude 'com/mysql/cj/LocalizedErrorMessages.properties'
        exclude 'com/mysql/cj/configurations/maxPerformance.properties'
    }
```